# Cannot find Canvas Page setting

Tags: facebook, canvas, settings

i've noticed that fb application settings on facobook.com/developers has changed singificantly. Problem is where to find Canvas Page specification as was in old way like "http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/" where XXXXXXX was editable? Where can I find this setting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **App Namespace** now, under the Basic info section.

Comment: Thanx a lot buddy a knew it should be easy.